How to optimize wavelength of a photodiode exclusively to single wavelength?
I have a laser diode with parameters:
a. Laser Wavelength: 785 nm
b. Laser Power: (0 – 100) uW
c. Laser Modulation: 1 KHz
I need to design a photodiode circuit based on these parameters. I plan on using MTAPD-06-007 photodiode which has a peak sensitivity wavelength of 800nm and spectral response of (400 - 1100 nm). Is there a way to optimize the wavelength exclusively for 785nm? How do I go about designing the circuit.

Not electronicaly. Maybe an optical filter in front of the diode.

I'd pick a different device that is spectrally on one edge at 750 nm then, I'd use a grin-lens for rejecting the optical spectrum at longer wavelengths (say above 800 nm). I don't think you will get much better than this at under $100. It cannot be done electrically; you need at least one optical filter.

What exactly do you mean by optimize? The diode already covers the wavelength. Just keep out interfering wavelengths that it is sensitive to. If you haven't already considered the idea look up anti-stokes (up conversion) phosphors that respond directly to 785 nm (there are some -- look in the literature) and use a different diode and thin film filters, etc. Be creative and think. But you write so little about the details of your situation that I certainly can't be of much help. Maybe someone else has a working crystal ball. Mine's busted.

@Andyaka pd response tends to fall off very quickly for wavelengths longer than the peak. Using a device with peak at 750 when trying to receive 785 nm isn't likely to work well.

MTAPD-06-007 photodiode has optimized sensitivity at 800 nm. That should work well at 785 nm.

@liaifat85 You are right it should at 785 nm, the responsivity may be slightly lower than at 800 nm, but it can still detect light efficiently. So, what effect does it have on the photocurrent of the circuit or after I convert it into output voltage using transimpedance amplifier?

@periblepsis You are right it should at 785 nm, the responsivity may be slightly lower than at 800 nm, but it can still detect light efficiently. So, what effect does it have on the photocurrent of the circuit or after I convert it into output voltage using transimpedance amplifier?

@solitude_surfer Who cares if the responsivity is lower at 785nm? This has no bearing on the circuit design. If the only source of light that the photodiode sees is the laser, than the photocurrent is directly related to the emission of the laser line. Adjust transimpedance gain appropriately. No optics needed (apart from the coupling optics. But that's your problem).

A bandpass interference filter should block all light outside that wavelength. They're available from Andover Corp., Edmund Optics, , Knight Optical, and elsewhere. Those citations are just examples, look for something that meets your requirements and budget.
BTW, be careful to use interference filters correctly: the angle of incidence and the polarization of the beam affect transmission greatly.

From comments,

what effect does it have on the photocurrent of the circuit or after I convert it into output voltage using transimpedance amplifier?

Operating at 785nm, versus the 800nm peak, is as given in the datasheet:
MTAPD-06-005/006/007/008 800nm Avalanche Photodiode | Marktech Optoelectronics Fig.1

They actually plot the peak at 880nm, though it may vary from part to part so who really knows for sure.  The responsivity at 785nm is about 0.482 A/W, all of 4% below the nominal specification, and a far smaller change than due to manufacturing variation (specified minimum responsivity is 0.35).
You will have far greater variance due to alignment and focus of the optical path.
Responsivity is given in units of amperes photocurrent per incident watts, so this has a proportional effect on circuit current or TIA voltage.
